# Close blocking QLocalServer from other thread

Tags: qt, qthread, qtcpsocket, qlocalsocket, qlocalserver

I am running a blocking `QLocalServer` in a thread:

```
void QThread::stopServer()
{
    m_abort = true;
    m_server.close(); // QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread 
}

void QThread::run()
{
    m_server = new QLocalServer();
    m_server->Listen("PipeName");
    while (!m_abort)
    {
        if (m_server->waitForNewConnection())
        {
            // handle the connection
        }
    }
    delete m_server;
}
```

How can the server be closed from another thread? Or is the only way to use non-blocking events?

Regards,

Comment: Why are you using a thread at all?  Just create the `QLocalServer` on the main/GUI thread and connect to its [`newConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalserver.html#newConnection) signal.

Comment: The ``QLocalServer`` is used in an application which is not based on ``QCoreApplication``.

Answer (score 0):

Why just not wait until `run()` closes or deletes the connection itself, after `m_abort` will be set?

```
void QThread::stopServer()
{
    m_abort = true; // shall be thread-safe (std::atomic<bool>, etc)
    wait(); // It’s optional to use it here
}

void QThread::run()
{
    m_server = new QLocalServer();
    m_server->Listen("PipeName");
    while (!m_abort)
    {
        if (m_server->waitForNewConnection())
        {
            /* Most likely you cannot handle the connection
            which was closed in another place, therefore сlose (delete)
            it after leaving here */
        }
    }
    delete m_server;
}
```

Please note you can use the standard [QThread::requestInterruption](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#requestInterruption) and [isInterruptionRequested()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#isInterruptionRequested) methods instead of creating own `m_abort` variable.

From the doc:

> This function can be used to make long running tasks cleanly
>   interruptible. Never checking or acting on the value returned by this
>   function is safe, however it is advisable do so regularly in long
>   running functions. **Take care not to call it too often, to keep the
>   overhead low.**

So you can write:

```
void QThread::stopServer()
{
    requestInterruption();
    wait(); // It’s optional to use it here
}

void QThread::run()
{
    m_server = new QLocalServer();
    m_server->Listen("PipeName");
    while (!isInterruptionRequested())
    {
        if (m_server->waitForNewConnection(100)) // 100 ms for not to call too often
        {
            /* Most likely you cannot handle the connection
            which was closed in another place, therefore сlose (delete)
            it after leaving here */
        }
    }
    delete m_server;
}
```